# devise omniauth with google fails with redirect_mismatch after clicking authorize button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth

I'm using devise 3.5 with rails 4.2.5,omniauth-gplus gem, mongoid 5, and ruby 2.2.3.

I have created my credentials at google console and have these redirect URIs:
http://127.0.0.1:3000/researchers/sign_in
http://127.0.0.1:3000/github/researchers/auth/gplus/callback
http://localhost:3000/github/researchers/auth/gplus/callback
http://localhost:3000/researchers/sign_in

the researchers/sign_in is the sign in page.

let's see the application with screenshots:
the root page:
[image: sign up page]
I click the last click(yes not beautiful I know, I'm focusing on functionality right now, css later).

the result:
[image: google plus sign in page]

I enter password and result:
[image: authorization page]

I click "سماح" which is the arabic translation of "authorize" , on this point I get this in my log:

```
Started GET "/github/researchers/auth/gplus/callback?state=6ee7df2d55e954dca0c7246c327a6639028eb5b0002534a4&code=4/q9-AlF5WKA3pXVCsz-BAt4xmmmjrGKfnJrzFNyZkZYc" for ::1 at 2015-12-09 23:15:41 +0200
I, [2015-12-09T23:15:41.262260 #2041]  INFO -- omniauth: (gplus) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2015-12-09T23:15:43.414828 #2041] ERROR -- omniauth: (gplus) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, redirect_uri_mismatch: 
{
  "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
}
Processing by Researchers::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"6ee7df2d55e954dca0c7246c327a6639028eb5b0002534a4", "code"=>"4/q9-AlF5WKA3pXVCsz-BAt4xmmmjrGKfnJrzFNyZkZYc"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/researchers/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 7ms
[2015-12-09 23:15:43] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:13 
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


Started GET "/researchers/sign_in" for ::1 at 2015-12-09 23:15:43 +0200
Processing by Researchers::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered researchers/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (10.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_links.html.erb (27.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 145ms (Views: 143.2ms)
```

From what I see devise sends state and code params to the callback URI and google refuses it because none of my redirect URIs have paramaters, those paramaters are dynamic they are different on every attempt.

I only have Google+ API enabled and need only this, that's why I'm not using omniauth-google-oauth2.

I've looked the google documentation, they don't tell how to use library but how to do it in hand.

I also looked in other SO questions, most of them are using omniauth-google-oauth2 gem not omniauth-gplus and anyway most of them gets this message on the click of login button while I get it only after clicking "authorize" button.

here is my rake routes:

```
                            Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                         Controller#Action
                          root GET      /                                                   researchers#new
        new_researcher_session GET      /researchers/sign_in(.:format)                      researchers/sessions#new
            researcher_session POST     /researchers/sign_in(.:format)                      researchers/sessions#create
    destroy_researcher_session DELETE   /researchers/sign_out(.:format)                     researchers/sessions#destroy
 researcher_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /github/researchers/auth/:provider(.:format)        researchers/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/gplus/}
  researcher_omniauth_callback GET|POST /github/researchers/auth/:action/callback(.:format) researchers/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:gplus)
           researcher_password POST     /researchers/password(.:format)                     researchers/passwords#create
       new_researcher_password GET      /researchers/password/new(.:format)                 researchers/passwords#new
      edit_researcher_password GET      /researchers/password/edit(.:format)                researchers/passwords#edit
                               PATCH    /researchers/password(.:format)                     researchers/passwords#update
                               PUT      /researchers/password(.:format)                     researchers/passwords#update
cancel_researcher_registration GET      /researchers/cancel(.:format)                       researchers#cancel
       researcher_registration POST     /researchers(.:format)                              researchers#create
   new_researcher_registration GET      /researchers/sign_up(.:format)                      researchers#new
  edit_researcher_registration GET      /researchers/edit(.:format)                         researchers#edit
                               PATCH    /researchers(.:format)                              researchers#update
                               PUT      /researchers(.:format)                              researchers#update
                               DELETE   /researchers(.:format)                              researchers#destroy
       researcher_confirmation POST     /researchers/confirmation(.:format)                 researchers/confirmations#create
   new_researcher_confirmation GET      /researchers/confirmation/new(.:format)             researchers/confirmations#new
                               GET      /researchers/confirmation(.:format)                 researchers/confirmations#show
                   researchers GET      /researchers(.:format)                              researchers#index
                               POST     /researchers(.:format)                              researchers#create
                new_researcher GET      /researchers/new(.:format)                          researchers#new
               edit_researcher GET      /researchers/:id/edit(.:format)                     researchers#edit
                    researcher GET      /researchers/:id(.:format)                          researchers#show
                               PATCH    /researchers/:id(.:format)                          researchers#update
                               PUT      /researchers/:id(.:format)                          researchers#update
                               DELETE   /researchers/:id(.:format)                          researchers#destroy
```

here is my callbacks controller:

```
    class Researchers::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  # You should configure your model like this:
  # devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:twitter]

  # You should also create an action method in this controller like this:
  # def twitter
  # end    
  # More info at:
  # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#omniauth
  #google+ callback
  def gplus
    @researcher = Researcher.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @researcher.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @researcher, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Google+") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.gplus_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_researcher_registration_url
    end
  end
  # GET|POST /resource/auth/twitter
  def passthru
    super
  end

  # GET|POST /users/auth/twitter/callback
  def failure
    super
  end

  # protected

  # The path used when OmniAuth fails
  # def after_omniauth_failure_path_for(scope)
  #   super(scope)
  # end
end
```

and last my model:

```
  class Researcher
  include Mongoid::Document
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable,:confirmable,:recoverable,:omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:gplus]
  #, :rememberable, :trackable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time,localize: true

  ## Rememberable
  #field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  #field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  #field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  #field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  #field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  #field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  ## Confirmable
  field :confirmation_token,   type: String
  field :confirmed_at,         type: Time,localize: true
  field :confirmation_sent_at, type: Time,localize: true
  field :unconfirmed_email,    type: String # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # field :failed_attempts, type: Integer, default: 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # field :unlock_token,    type: String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # field :locked_at,       type: Time
  field :username, type: String
  field :provider,type: String
  field :uid,type: String

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |researcher|
      if data = session["devise.gplus"] && session["devise.gplus"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        researcher.email = data["email"] if researcher.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |researcher|
    researcher.email = auth.info.email
    researcher.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]       
  end
end
end
```

I'm ready for supplying any information As I know that redirect_uri_mismatch is a common issue :).

### Edit

I was wrong , the state and code params are coming from google, google gets the failure callback in my controller with those paramters.

I'm clueless , what to do to satisfy google ?